# How to display newer Google Map InfoWindows on top of older ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am having Google Map with InfoWindows being added dynamically. The issue is, when two InfoWindows overlap, the recent one won't always be on top of older ones.

How can I make sure latter InfoWindow always show up on top of all other InfoWIndows using Javascript/jQuery?

The InfoWindows are added when I receive new images and coordinates through websocket. Here is my code:

```
function addToMap(image) {
    console.log("In addToMap...");

    coordinates = image[2].split(',');
    pin=new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);

    if(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var markerIcon = image_car_icon;

    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:pin,
        zIndexProcess: function( m )
        {
            return 9999999 + pin_count;
        },
        icon:markerIcon
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

    pin_count++;

    if(image[0] != "NOP") {
        popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:'<image id="pin_' + pin_count + '" src="data:image/png;base64,' + image[1] +'"/>',
        });

        popup.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

popup is the InfoWindow created when I get a new image. Suppose two images have almost same coordinates, I want the second InfoWindow to be on top (z-index). But, most of the time, the first window stays on top.

Comment: How are you creating your infowindows?  Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution. I am manually modifying the z-index of the marker by using the image as the handle. `marker_count` is a running marker, so the `z-index` will be greater than the previous marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(popup, 'domready', function() {
    console.log("DOM READY...........................");

    // Bring latest Image to top            
    e = $('#pin_' + img_count).parent().parent().parent().parent();

    e.css({
        'z-index' : (99999 + marker_count),
    });
});
```